# Graph theory - a separation property of a normal tree

Tags: graph-theory

I'm a novice in this new field of mathematics and would like to ask you for a more concrete explanation underlying the single-line explanation on the textbook.

After a brief introduction of the definition of a normal tree in a graph, these two lemma immediately follows. Author emphasizes the usefulness of a normal tree as an examining tool for the structure of a graph: it projects its separation properties onto the graph.

I understand the first lemma but the very last part of the second one is bothering me a lot. How can we use the result in (i) to prove that there are no other minimal elements? As I understand, it at least needs to precede that the given component C := G-S has a normal tree in it.

Of course there is a theorem that states the existence of normal (spanning) trees in finite connected graphs, but the theorem hasn't been introduced since. So I conjecture that author herein assumes a quite straightforward proof of a weaker theorem. Would anyone help me with this?

*Because I'm not familiar with this field, I'm worried that I might be missing some essential understanding. That's why I'm trying to avoid those theorems covered later on the textbook.

[refer to the pg.16 for the book](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ebilley/classes/562.winter.2018/articles/GraphTheory.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $C$ is a component of $G-S$ and that $x$ and $y$ are minimal vertices of $C$. $C$ is connected, so there is an $x$-$y$ path in $C$. By (i) we know that this path contains a vertex $v\in\lceil x\rceil\cap\lceil y\rceil$. Then $v\le x$ and $v\in C$, so $v=x$, since $x$ is minimal in $C$. Similarly, $v\le y$, so $v=y$. But then $x=v=y$, and $C$ must have a unique minimal vertex.

Comment: Is "vertex $v \in \lceil x \rceil \cap \lceil y \rceil$" supposed to also be $z$?

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo: Actually, $z$ was supposed to be $v$, but yes, they’re supposed to be the same, and I’ve corrected them all to $v$.

Comment: I totally forgot that the vertex is in the path which is finally 'in C'. I think the missing of the condition made me only cling on to justifying the existence of a normal tree in C. Now I feel relieved to understand the true mechanism of the proof. Thank you for reminding me of so!!

Comment: @user245305: You’re welcome!